# Linux - Process get as much resources as possible but give out resources when other processes coming in

Tags: linux, nice

I need to run a process `A` as much resources as possible when the machine is free, but gives out CPU once there's high-priority processes are started.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: So what happened when you tried? `nice` is the tool for the job (although -19 seems a bit excessive), what else do you need?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add these details. Also explain why you chose to give it such a low priority instead of the default `-10` (which is probably what you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve what you want. You can use `nice`, `cgroups`, `cpulimit` to limit the cpu usage. You are in right direction by giving nice -19 right command to give niceness is `nice -n 19 Program name`.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum overkill is to use a process scheduler such as [HTCondor](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/) or [SLURM](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html), though this perhaps better suits larger numbers of systems and where there is sufficient knowledge around to setup and maintain the scheduler. These schedulers offer all sorts of means to divvy up CPU and other resources (at the cost of a not so simple learning curve).